# Where is Global Code defined in Blue Prism?

Tags: blueprism

Where is Global Code (https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-7-0/en-us/frmStagePropertiesObjectInfo.htm) defined in Blue Prism?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Studio, View or Edit the desired Business Object.
2. Double click on the Object Properties (in this example, on the first Page of the Object).  You can also right click on this box and choose Properties.
   [image]
3. A Business Object Properties will appear with a tab for Global Code
   [image]

I'm new to Blue Prism so I spent some quality time looking for this.